# Can ingesting a mosquito make you sick?

Tags: disease-transmission, infectious-diseases, mosquito

I just accidentally ate a mosquito. I am afraid, what if the mosquito just drank blood of a HIV infected person, will I get the infection too, or some other disease?

Comment: @CountIblis <comment deleted> Please do not answer in the comments. If you have an answer, please post it below.

Answer (score 5):

Positively, **no**.

HIV is **not** [spread](http://www.cdc.gov/hiv/basics/transmission.html) by mosquitoes.

You **cannot** contract any disease from swallowing  a mosquito.

[Here](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/PH/PH709_Transmission/PH709_Transmission_print.html), is a very large list of all the things that you could have caught :) If you were bitten.

Comment: While this is correct for HIV, the OP also mentioned "other diseases". Can you add something on that?

Comment: woah. The question changed 1 minute ago :P I'll add it soon (I was asleep)

Comment: That was in the question even before I edited. You can always look up the edit history.  I have no idea who you mean by Chris.

Comment: "You cannot contract any disease from swallowing a mosquito." what if the mosquito paws had poop or fecal residues?